# Access Switch Value From Different View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, view, uiswitch

I have two View Controller classes **Class A** & **Class B** 
There is a UIswitch in **Class A**, depending on whether it is turned ON or OFF it should cause some action to be performed in **Class B** when a button click in **Class B**.

What i am trying to do is save the state of the switch in **Class A** and then retrieve it onto **Class B**

In **Class A**  i did the following to save the state of the switch

```
NSUserDefaults *switchState=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(self.switch.on){
[switchState setBool:YES forKey:@"ON"];
}
else {
      if (!self.switch.on){
      [switchState setBool:NO forKey:@"OFF"];
     }

}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

In **Class B** i check the state of the switch and perform an action based on the state. I used the following code in **Class B**.

```
-(void)whenButtonPressed{

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ON"]){

 //  Perform Some action

 }else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OFF"]){
//Perform Some other action

}
}
```

In **Class A**  when switch is turned On or Off it satisfies correct **If** or **Else If** Condition block

But in **Class B** , it only satisfies the first **If** condition regardless of the result in **Class A**  i.e even if the switch is turned off.

Can anyone please point out what my mistake is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get it a bit wrong how `NSUserDefaults` works.
If you have 1 switch for which you want to save the state, you use 1 key.

Save it that way when the switch gets pressed:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:self.switch.on forKey:@"switch1"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Retrieve it:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL switchOn = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"switch1"];

if (switchOn) {
// switch is enabled
}
else {
// not enabled
}
```